# Immaculate inning

Tags: baseball, mlb

Has any pitcher in the majors ever thrown two or more consecutive immaculate innings? Where an immaculate inning is 3 consecutive strike outs on 9 pitches.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found my own answer. Baseball Reference has a section of general information called the bullpen. if that section they had a list of all recorded immaculate innings and there has never been two in a single game much less consecutive.

Comment: Could you possibly add a link to the appropriate section on the Baseball Reference web site?

Comment: Here's a list: http://www.baseball-almanac.com/feats/feats17.shtml